# Can we use Dynamic Apex to Share a Record?

Tags: apex, sharing

One of the most common use cases not supported by sharing rules is when we have a lookup field to the user object and whomever is selected in the lookup field will automatically get read/write access to the record.

Can we design a reusable code/trigger to do this? Its one of the most common things that we had to create a trigger for.

More information on creating a trigger:
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Using_Apex_Managed_Sharing_to_Create_Custom_Record_Sharing_Logic

I've had some success using the following code:

```
LeadShare leadShare = new LeadShare();
leadShare.ParentId = '00QC00000121LCI';
leadShare.UserOrGroupId = '005C0000003N5lT';
leadShare.AccessLevel = 'edit';
insert leadShare;
```

Here are some of my considerations:
 - How can we get the different rowCause from Apex?
 - How can we determine if the OBJECTNAME__Share is available?

Feel free to share other information that need to be considered. Thanks!

Comment: This is dredging up an old question :) (saw it in the related sidebar). I answered a question about detecting the sharing model of an object, it was done using dynamic apex: [Get object sharing setting on Organization-Wide Defaults](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/9487/80)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just tried this with an object called Test, with a Reason also called Test. Hope this helps!

```
Schema.SObjectType testShareType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Test__Share');
SObject testShare = testShareType.newSObject();
testShare.put('ParentId', 'a00G00000099pyM');
testShare.put('UserOrGroupId', UserInfo.getUserId());
testShare.put('AccessLevel', 'Read');
testShare.put('RowCause', 'Test__c');
insert testShare;
```

If the object does not have a sharing object 'testShareType' in the example above will be null.

Comment: You'd prolly need a try catch around checking the existence of the Share table, as this will be available only if the Sharing Model for the object is Private. Don think there is a describe route to query the object sharing model.

Comment: Yeah did have a look for describe, much like the Chatter enablement, sadly nothing as you say. I also tested with an object without Sharing Model set to private and got a null rather than exception, so he should be good checking for that.

Comment: I guess we will just have to hardcode it for the standard objects right? Like in this case its using LeadId instead pf ParentId and LeadAccessLevel instead of AccessLevel.

Comment: Ah another good old design difference with Standard objects vs Custom objects! :-) Well you can determine via Describe (see Schema.DescribeSObjectResult.isCustom method) if the object is standard or custom. Then from that, providing Salesforce have mangled the field names consistently, mangle the field names based on the Standard object name.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I'm considering a product that addresses the limitation that we have in terms of sharing rules to a specific user or a lookup field in any record. Your answer definitely helps!