# Get object sharing setting on Organization-Wide Defaults

Tags: apex, sharing, sobject

Is it possible to know, via apex code, if a certain object is Private, Public Read-Only or Public Read/Write?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the Standard object, you can use Organization object to achieve this, query like,

```
Organization org = [Select Id, DefaultAccountAccess, DefaultContactAccess, DefaultLeadAccess, DefaultOpportunityAccess from Organization];

System.debug(org);
```

Query this object to obtain information about an organization's settings. Only one `organization` record exists per organization.

for the details, see the [Organization object model documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm).

Comment: Thank you. That's what i'm looking for. I didn't know that object had these fields.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to test for sharing of custom objects is to check the global describe Map.

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> tokens = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
if(tokens.containsKey('MyCustomObject__Share')) {
    //Share object exists, therefore custom object is private or public read only

    //Still need to use dynamic apex because this code won't compile if MyCustomObject__Share does not exist
    SObject share = tokens.get('MyCustomObject__Share').newSObject();
    share.put('ParentId', customObjectInstance.Id);
    share.put('UserOrGroupId', UserInfo.getUserId());
    //API Name of the Sharing reason, or don't populate if the reason is Manual
    share.put('RowCause', 'Sharing_Reason__c');
} else {
    //Share does not exist custom object is public read write
}
```

As you have already discovered, this is only for custom objects, @JiaHu's answer explains how to get the sharing level of a standard object.

Comment: If the MyCustomObject__Share object doesn't exist it enters the ELSE, but wouldn't it still cause an error if you reference MyCustomObject__Share inside your IF?

Comment: @Phil, it's only a string key in the global describe map, I'm not actually referencing the share objects describe information or token

Comment: Ah sorry, I was assuming you'd have some references to the MyCustomObject__Share record inside the if statement (some type of logic assuming it passes the IF). Assuming that was the case wouldn't that cause an error?

Comment: @Phil, I updated the question with code for dynamically sharing a record

Answer (score 0):

Guess this should help you :

SELECT Id,ParentId,UserOrGroupId,RowCause,AccessLevel FROM ObjectApiName__Share

Comment: What i want to know is if an certan object is Private, Public or Public RO. If the Sharing table exists, like CustomObject__Share, then I know that this object is private ou public read only, if not it is public read/write. But with standard object I can't use this. For example if I change the object Account to Public Read/Write the object AccountShare keep existing.