# error: Unable to change sharing model because sharing objects are referenced by the following components

Tags: sharing, apex-sharing, org-wide-defaults

I'm developing a managed package which has some apex sharing functionality built into it. In the customer test org I'm attempting to set one of the referenced objects to be public read/write instead of private and I'm getting the error:

```
Unable to change sharing model because sharing objects are referenced by the following components:
```

Is there a way to update the code that references sharing to be more dynamic and avoid this conflict. Allowing the customer to choose to make the object public if they don't want to use the apex managed sharing functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's complaining because the change would hide the tables like `AccountShare`. Similar thing happens when you convert Lookup to Master-Detail and you have either `*Share` tables or references to `child__c.ownerid` in the code.

Can you change your code to dynamic apex? A describe call to learn whether `ObjectX__Share` exists is accessible + [dynamic DML](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_dml.htm) to populate the object & insert the sharing entries...

Essentially similar tricks you have to do if you don't know if target org has `CurrencyIsoCode` field enabled or not...

Comment: Yeah I'm going to give this a shot

Comment: That worked, I referenced this question for some syntax as well: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7363/get-object-sharing-setting-on-organization-wide-defaults